# Cannot access PC from Internet via IPv6

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ipv6, acl

I am trying to make my computer accessible from the internet for SSH via IPv6. Unfortunately, nothing I tried so far has worked:

- The PC is running Windows 11, 23H2
- I can use the IPv6 address (from `ipconfig` / https://api6.ipify.org/) of my PC to log in via SSH when I'm in the same local network. This suggests to me that the problem is on the Router side
- In the router settings (Zyxel AX7501-B1), I tried to configure an ACL to allow access to the relevant TCP port (note that the destination is set to ANY for debugging only):

  Summary view:
  [image]

  Detailed view:
  [image]
- Trying to SSH into the PC from outside the home network always results in `debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10051, io:00000246C24F1830` (the exact same command works from within the home network)
- I even tried to disable both the routers & PCs firewall temporarily, still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do your Windows firewall rules (`wf.msc`) allow connections from outside the subnet? If you install Wireshark and start a capture, does it see any inbound packets to the port?

Comment: You are forwarding to port 23. The default SSH port is 22. What is your ssh command?

Comment: @u1686_grawity As I wrote in the question, I tried it also with the Windows firewall disabled. Anyway, trying with Wireshark shows no packets when connecting from outside, but does show some when connecting from inside the network

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I am forwarding port 23 on purpose, the SSH server & command are configured appropriately. The command is `ssh lukas@<ipv6> -p 23 -vvv -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_file`

Comment: `This suggests to me that the problem is on the Router side` or the ipv6 address is not a publicly routable one - i.e a ULA (starts with FCxx or more likely FDxx)

Comment: or the fact that you destination address looks blank - in fact, that whole config looks underdone

Comment: @JaromandaX The IP starts with `2a02:`, so should be publicly routable as far as I can tell? (Also, as noted, the IP is obtained from https://api6.ipify.org/, which should give the internet-facing (or whatever it's called) IPv6 address as far as I understand). Regarding the second comment: Yeah, the config looks a bit empty: However, if you look at the summary line at the very top (first image), it shows the source and destination as `Any/128`, which is why I assume the config treats empty fields as wildcards (it will also complain about missing inputs)